# text-decoration: none on anchor tag is not working

Tags: html, css

I tried almost everything when it comes to remove that 'underline' thing. But I am unable to remove it. I want to remove that underline from the anchor tag. I am providing my HTML and CSS code.

**HTML :**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat+Brush|Permanent+Marker" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav>
            <h1>ABC<br> DEF</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#facilities">One</a></li>
            <li a href="#location"><a>Two</a></li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
        <!--Photo comes here-->



        <!--Can Contact me goes here-->


</body>
</html>
```

**CSS :**

```
/*Custom CSS starts from here*/


body {
    font-family: 'Caveat Brush';
}

h1 {
    font-size: 72px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 32px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Please add your CSS as well.

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot. I added.

Comment: your code is working for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLZgeO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `text-decoration: none`. may be you need to override it with more precedence by using `!important`.

```
li a {
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

I can't reproduce the issue you are facing with your provided code.

Here's the fiddle for your reference: https://jsfiddle.net/oqoajzbp/